# JAVA - How to pass array into @NamedNativeQuery

Tags: java, sql, jpa

Do you know how to pass this attribute (array of Calendar) into @NamedNativeQuery?

'["1996-01-01 12:00:00","1996-01-01 17:00:00"]'

I tried the follow way but doesn't work.

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
      name = "BusinessHours.deleteBusinessHours",
      query = "delete from business_hours " +
              "where company_address_id = ?1 and " +
              "hours = [?2,?3]"
)
```

Edit:
Native query in postgres is:

```
DELETE FROM business_hours 
WHERE company_address_id = 7 
AND hours = '["1996-01-01 18:15:00","1996-01-01 18:30:00"]'
```

Comment: Did you try with in? ...and hours in ?2 and pass array instead of 2 arguments

Comment: Can you write it in detail because I don't understand you.

Comment: query = "delete from business_hours where company_address_id = ?1 and hours in ?2" As ?2 you pass array of dates

Comment: No, it doesn't work again..

Comment: try query = "delete from business_hours where company_address_id = ?1 and hours = ARRAY[?2, ?3]"

Comment: No it does not work again..

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your delete statement, `business_hours.hours` is typed as a character in DB. So what you need is to serialize your array into a String matching the format expected by your DB, then pass that String via a single placeholder:

```
query = "delete from business_hours where company_address_id = ?1 and hours = ?2"
```